# Every how many days the Metrics Data form SharePoint store apps will change?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Every how many days the **Metrics Data** form SharePoint store apps will change?

I checked it just now and the Last updated is March 10 2015!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per msdn link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn782344.aspx

Metric data should be updated every few days. The exact count is not provided.

Comment: thank you for response, it seem there is issue with there service these days

Comment: Yes cloud services are unpredictable and we have no control over those. Better check with MS support.